# How to show more fonts in Preview?

Tags: preview, font

Using cmd+t while annotating an image with text in Preview I don't find all the fonts I have installed. For example there is no Verdana or Century Gothic.
How can I view them?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

In `Preview.app` look for the installed font under **Collection → All Fonts**.

[image]

Comment: huh? Where is that?

Comment: @simpatico I've added a picture. Sorry for the inconvenience :)

Comment: I had looked there too: http://screencast.com/t/eQ3f0wUu

Answer (score 0):

1. Copy the fonts from `/Library/Fonts/Microsoft` into `/Library/Fonts`
2. Restart computer